# Knockout.js how to access the inner object property on data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

I've a super simple knockout code below:

```
var data ={
    "Id" : 1001,
    "SalePrice" : 12345,
    "ListPrice" : 333,
    "ShortDesc" : "Tayler 12345E",
    "Description" : " Long Description"
};


var viewModel={
    dataTest: ko.observable(data)
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

<span data-bind="text: dataTest.SalePrice"></span>
```

Basically, I've passed the whole data object to observable property dataTest. I would have thought it's easy enough to access the property of inner object with dot notation. But's not.

Could someone please help how to make above code to work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's an observable now (ie, it's a function).  You need to call the function.

```
<span data-bind="text: dataTest().SalePrice"></span>
```

[Editing Akshat's fiddle to match](http://jsfiddle.net/sZYcn/).

Not sure why this is an advantage over nesting a proper hierarchy, however.  What the OP is asking is pretty anti-pattern.  I think you might want to look over [the page on binding context Akshat suggests](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) to see how to create the `dataTest` as a parent object and then drill down in your markup.

Comment: Nice catch about the observable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is it possible to itarate over "data" object in order to access all properties at once?

Comment: @stratovarius That's probably a new question. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking in this context, since `SalePrice` is a single int. If you mean can you grab everything from `dataTest()`, you certainly can. But doing so within a single bound object like the one here doesn't make a lot of sense. But perhaps [you want a computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)? Hard to tell -- search SO for a similar question to what you're asking, and if nothing pops up, feel free to ask a new one!

Comment: I would like to access dataTest()'s properties with the help of foreach.

Comment: Very nice to see that you first add a solution, before questioning the OP's approach.

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan Just google for knockoutjs foreach. Very easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2tyM/).All you need to do is this

```
<span data-bind="text: salePrice "></span>
```

This will populate the span element with sale price defined in the view model.

From your question it appears to me that what you are trying to do is bind the view model to different elements of the html page. To achieve this you can pass an `id` parameter to the apply bindings to bind a specific view model to a specific section of the page. Like this

```
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel,document.getElementById('id'));
```

If you are looking to directly access the view model use the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). In this case you need the `$data` binding context.So the binding in span will change to

```
<span data-bind="text:$data.salePrice"></span>
```

Comment: I know we can do that directly. But, I'm trying to access the object which is assigned to property of viewModel.

Comment: This is very long process when we really have permission to access through chaining

Answer (score 2):

It can be also written as:

```
<span data-bind="text: dataTest()['SalePrice']"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page is read only, and the view model will not change, (as in my case) then you don't need the observable.

You can also make the code sample work by doing this:

```
var viewModel={
    dataTest: data
};
```

Then you can access your properties in the data binding with simple dot notation.

```
<span data-bind="text: dataTest.SalePrice"></span>
```

Using a context or **[with](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)** binding was not desirable in my case since I would have to continually switch back and forth between 2 objects in a comparison table.

Comment: The OP does not say if 2 way data binding is necessary, so this is another answer to the question.  I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Call to ko.observable needs to be moved from MVVM to HTML element:

```
    var data ={
    "Id" : 1001,
    "SalePrice" : 12345,
    "ListPrice" : 333,
    "ShortDesc" : "Tayler 12345E",
    "Description" : " Long Description"
};


var viewModel={
    dataTest: data
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

<span data-bind="text: ko.observable(dataTest.SalePrice)"></span>
```