# Knockout - Access property in array of objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I was taking a look at another question ([Knockout.js how to access the inner object property on data-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879439/knockout-js-how-to-access-the-inner-object-property-on-data-bind)) and saw how to bind a property within an object. I was wondering how to bind a property from multiple objects within an array and assumed it would be a quick tweak on the answer:

```
var data = [
    {
        "Id" : 1001,
        "SalePrice" : 12345,
        "ListPrice" : 333,
        "ShortDesc" : "Tayler 12345E",
        "Description" : " Long Description"
    },
    {
        "Id" : 1002,
        "SalePrice" : 23456,
        "ListPrice" : 444,
        "ShortDesc" : "Tayler 23456F",
        "Description" : " Long Description"
    }
];

var viewModel={
    dataTest: ko.observable(data)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

<div data-bind="foreach: dataTest">
    <span data-bind="text: dataTest().SalePrice"></span>
</div>
```

I'm getting an error saying that `dataTest` is not defined, but I can't work out why this is happening. Could someone take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Amended Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nimaek/sZYcn/132/

Comment: You don't need the `dataTest().` qualifier within the `foreach` -- it should just say: `span data-bind="text: SalePrice"'`

Comment: If you _do_ still need to reference the current item directly, you can use `$data`, as in `data-bind="text: $data.SalePrice"`.  More common if you need to pass it off to another function etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside binding `foreach`. Use

```
<span data-bind="text: SalePrice"></span>
```