# Access the Knockout Obeserable object property while binding HTML

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I, have a observable property as below

```
var ReportViewmodel = { 
    responseDetailsSetUpData: ko.observable({
            Pagination: ko.observable({
                Pager: ko.observable({
                    TotalItems: ko.observable(),
                    CurrentPage: ko.observable(),
                    PageSize: ko.observable(),
                    TotalPages: ko.observable(),
                    StartPage: ko.observable(),
                    EndPage: ko.observable(),
                    ShowingItem: ko.observable()
                })
            }),
            Data: ko.observableArray([])
        })
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(ReportViewmodel, document.getElementById("ReportForm"));
});
```

when I, am trying to bind the property in the html I am getting an error as 
**$root.responseDetailsSetUpData(...).Pagination is not a function**

I try to access the property as describe in this link

[Knockout.js how to access the inner object property on data-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879439/knockout-js-how-to-access-the-inner-object-property-on-data-bind)

```
<td colspan="2" class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><span data-bind="text: $root.responseDetailsSetUpData().Pagination().Pager().ShowingItem"></span></td>
```

Where is the mistake I, am not able to figure it out.

Can anyone please let me know

Comment: Here is a fiddler that works with Knockout 2.0:  http://jsfiddle.net/muc6e072/.  As @notmeanymore says, perhaps `responseDetailsSetUpData` is not in the root of your viewmodel.

Comment: I, have updated the code

Comment: I updated the fiddler, without jQuery:  http://jsfiddle.net/muc6e072/2/.  Can you update this fiddler to give us an example that not works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure because your code you provided is not enough to say but I think the problem is your $root. In this case may be your $root is not the vm that have responseDetailsSetUpData

Comment: I, have updated the code. Please check and let me know

Comment: Why do you need to add $root to your binding?, can you provide more HTML code or post it to a code snippet?